# Haskell-ghc-mod: ghc-mod failed to launch. It is probably missing or misconfigured. ENOENT

Tags: haskell, ghc, atom-editor

```
Error: spawn ghc-mod ENOENT
PATH: /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
path: undefined
Path: undefined
Hide Stack Trace
Error
    at /Users/Mauritius/.atom/packages/haskell-ghc-mod/lib/ghc-mod/ghc-modi-process.coffee:60:28
    at exithandler (child_process.js:222:5)
    at ChildProcess.errorhandler (child_process.js:229:5)
    at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:169:7)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:198:12)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:344:16)
    at doNTCallback2 (node.js:441:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:17
```

Comment: can anyone help me? i fail to get haskell running in atom.

Comment: What did you do to get this error?  Is this haskell or Javascript?

Comment: what's the output of `ghc-mod debug` when you run it in the project directory?

Comment: Is it an error message from Atom? I guess either you didn't install ghc-mod or it's not in your PATH.

Comment: was not in path, i solved it thanks. As i am not good with terminal i had some problems.

Answer (score 2):

i ran into this problem right now, what i have done is to go Atom , in the header press Atom ->Preferences then Package, for the [image]ide-haskell package go to setting and set the path for stylish-haskell, then for haskell-ghc-mode package also set up ghc mod and ghc modi path